# UIWebView enable zoom and disable scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a `UITableView` where all the cells contain a `UIWebView`. I calculate the height of the content in the UIWebViewes and use dynamic cells so there should never be any scrolling in the WebViews.

This works fine.

Howerver now i need to enable zooming, i have done this using `scalesPageToFit = true`. This howerver enable scrolling in UIWebView, so when i try to scroll the TableView the WebView is scrolled instead.

How can i disable scrolling in WebView but have zooming enabled?

Comment: From a usability perspective, I would have thought that if you zoom you need scroll/pan to get at zoomed content which ends up out of view?

Comment: You might be better to create an overlay view that goes over the table when you select the UIWebView. So on select of the web view you bring the overlay to the front and move the UIWebView into it from the cell at exactly the same location on screen. You can then optionally animate  it bigger on screen. Very much like how Facebook etc explode out images when you select them. When user is finished put the UIWebView back and drop the overlay. Result is click on UIWebView to see exploded out version on screen you can scroll and pan then click outside area to return to the table.

Answer (score -1):

try doing webView.scrollView.bounce=NO;